# Simplest server to server authentication

Tags: rest, security, ssl

I have microservice on a new server/vps that will only ever be called via REST by monolith app to perform some heavy lifting and then post the operation results back to the monolith in few minutes.

How should I protect these two endpoints? I think my main goal, for now, is just preventing someone that found servers address to be able to do anything.

Almost every solution I google seems like overkill/premature optimization.

Is it sufficient that I generate random long token once on each machine and then just pass it to headers and check it's presence on the other end?

Do I even need to SSL this? As far as I understand we need SSL encryption for clients that are trying to send sensitive data via wireless or unsafe shared networks.

What are the chances(is it even possible?) that somebody is gonna eavesdrop between two digitalocean vps's sending data via http? Did it ever happen before ?

Answer (score 0):

> Q: Is it sufficient that I generate random long token once on each machine and then just pass it to headers and check it's presence on the other end?

A: Generally microservices are behind a GateKeeper/Gateway([nginx](http://nginx.org/),[haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)) so you can expose the endpoints you want. In your case I would recommend to create a [private network](https://blog.digitalocean.com/introducing-private-networking/) between the two vps's and expose your microservice on that internal IP.

> Q: Do I even need to SSL this? As far as I understand we need SSL encryption for clients that are trying to send sensitive data via wireless or unsafe shared networks.

A: No. If you use internal networks and don't expose to the public then there is no need for SSL/TLS. If you would do something with [Tier 3/4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_center#Data_center_levels_and_tiers) then you would need encryption for cross datacenter communication.

> Q: What are the chances(is it even possible?) that somebody is gonna eavesdrop between two digitalocean vps's sending data via http? Did it ever happen before ?

A: There are bots that scan for open ports on servers/computers and try to penetrate them with exploits. In all cases always use a firewall like UFW/firewalld.

So let's say you have two servers with these microservices using the internal private network from your favorite provider:

VPS1 (ip = 10.0.1.50)

```
FooBarService:1337
BarFooService:7331
```

VPS2 (ip = 10.0.1.51)

```
AnotherMicroService:9999
```

Now both VPS's can access each other's services by simply calling the ip + port.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few simple solutions you could use to authenticate both servers back and forth. The one I would recommend if you want to keep it simple, as you say, is [Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). As long as you're utilizing that over an SSL/HTTPS connection, it suffices as a super simple way to authenticate each end.

You state it is your main goal to protect these endpoints, but then ask if SSL/HTTP is even needed. If these servers are vulnerable to the web in any way, then I would say yes, your endpoints need to be protected, and if you're transmitting sensitive data, then you need to be sending it through a secure stream.

If you believe the data you're sending is not very sensitive, and is likely that no one that knows these two endpoints will even know how to properly manipulate your data by sending fake requests, then sure, you don't need any of this, but then you assume the risk and responsibility for if and when it ever is exposed. Basic Auth is super easy, and with [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) it's incredibly easy to obtain an SSL certificate for free. It's good experience, so may as well try it out and protect these endpoints and ensure that they're safe.